# How can I use maildrop to forward a copy to another email address?

Tags: postfix, filter, email

I have a postfix + virtual users setup. I have enabled maildrop as the delivery agent. How can I write a filter for a user so that if mail comes from a particular domain to that user a copy also goes to another email address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used maildrop to create recipes, but I believe something like this:

```
if ( /^From:.*domain\.com/:h ) {
  cc "!someothermail@domain2.com"
}
```

References:

- http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop.html
- http://www.courier-mta.org/maildropfilter.html

Comment: Thanks Jon for the pointer. That was something for me to start with. There is a slight correction to the above, maildrop requires a "!" to understand that it needs to be send via sendmail. It should cc "!someothermail@domain2.com"

Comment: I finally managed to get maildrop working with virtualusers in postfix details here http://www.netzary.com/blogs/2010/jul/01/postfix-virtual-usersmysql-maildrop/

Comment: @proy did you keep a copy of your blog post somewhere else ? I can't find it on the archive.org neither.